# routing.yml file doesn't work

Tags: routes

I'm working on an existing Drupal 8 site. I'm changing anything in routing.yml.

In a routing.yml file I have the following.

```
user_profile_update.callback:
  path: '/user-update'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\user_profile\Controller\ProfileUpdateController::updateUser'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
    _permission: 'access content'
```

I want to change the controller's method to 
`\Drupal\user_profile\Controller\ProfileUpdateController::updateUser123()`, but after editing the route definition, the `ProfileUpdateController` class is still using the `updateUser()` method.

I removed all the cache tables from the database with the following SQL, but the controller is still not using the `updateUser123()` method.

```
TRUNCATE cache_config;
TRUNCATE cache_container;
TRUNCATE cache_data;
TRUNCATE cache_default;
TRUNCATE cache_discovery;
TRUNCATE cache_dynamic_page_cache;
TRUNCATE cache_entity;
TRUNCATE cache_menu;
TRUNCATE cache_render;
TRUNCATE cache_toolbar;
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: if you rename the routing file to something random, and clear the cache, does the /user-update path still work?

Comment: yes  path works properly..

Comment: Well that should be impossible. Do you have multiple environments of your website? Perhaps you're changing the files of a particular environment and looking at a different environment on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that you have this in your routing.yml file:

```
user_profile_update.callback:
  path: '/user-update'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\user_profile\Controller\ProfileUpdateController::updateUser'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
    _permission: 'access content'
```

You're still calling updateUser and not updateUser123

Your controller should be looking like this:

```
class ProfileUpdateController extends ControllerBase {

  public function updateUser123() {
  //your code here
  }

}
```

And now you'll need to call the method:

```
user_profile_update.callback:
  path: '/user-update'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\user_profile\Controller\ProfileUpdateController::updateUser123'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Also I recommend clearing your cache with [Drush](http://www.drush.org/).
This will empty all caches and rebuild the data required for Drupal to execute the page request

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm calling  _controller: '\Drupal\user_profile\Controller\ProfileUpdateController::updateUser123' in my  routing.yml and renamed my controlller function updateUser123


Also, I have cleared Drupal cache using drush cr and also cleared cache tables in DB. Also, I have turned off Drupal caching. Still my code calls the old route method.

Comment: Have you tried re-creating your routing.yml file? Or you can perhaps try to reproduce it by doing the same in a new project?